# HR/Annual Leave Apps in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-integration

I was wondering if there are any apps for HR and personnel purposes that you can intergrate into SharePoint that will allow an employer to view requests for time off and either approve or deny requests. We have tried Kasper here in the office, and the problem with it is that it doesn't link up with O365 or update our calenders, so an app that does this would be preferable. Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their are couple of them, you can try

- [TIMEOFF – EMPLOYEES’ LEAVE REQUEST APP FOR SHAREPOINT](http://fild.net/en/news/timeoff-employees-leave-request-app-for-sharepoint/) try their
  pro version which has more functionality.
- [Work 365 Time](http://www.iotap.com/add-ons/sharepoint-apps/leave-and-time-management-work-365)

Their is any other way to manage via infopath but you need to a lot of effort.
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/151141.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Can these be integrated with Office 365 to sync with calenders?

Comment: i think they are, you can try it or contact them.